# Getting different crypto key results in Android using same password

Tags: java, android

every time I run the setup method using the same password, I get a different key result every time. I am using the key results to check if the decrypting password is correct, to prevent unnecessary decryption.

I ran the following code in java and I have no problems but in Android its an issue generating different keys. Can someone show me what is the problem and how to fix this.  I would like to have common software between Android and Java.

when I run the program in android I get the key org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEPBEKEY@12345678

When I run the program in java I get key 
com.sun.crypto.Provider.PBEKey@12345678

```
private static byte[] bytes;
  Cipher ecipher;
  Cipher dcipher;

  // 8-byte Salt
  byte[] salt = {
      (byte)0xA9, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0x32,
      (byte)0x56, (byte)0x35, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0x03
  };

  // Iteration count
  int iterationCount = 19;

  public String setup(String passPhrase) 
  {
      String output = null;
      try {
          // Create the key
          KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
          SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(
              "PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);

          ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
          dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());

          // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
          AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

          // Create the ciphers
          ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
          dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

          // print key
          System.out.println("key  = " + key);
          System.out.println("paramSpec  = " + paramSpec);


          output = key.toString();
      //    showToast("setting up key " + output);
      //    showToast("key size " + output.length());
          System.out.println("key Size " + output.length());

      } catch (java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
      } catch (java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException e) {
      } catch (javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException e) {
      } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      } catch (java.security.InvalidKeyException e) {
      }

      return output;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(
              "PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);
```

to

```
SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(
              "PBEWithMD5AndDES","BC").generateSecret(keySpec);
```

Like this you specifically ask for a crypto provider (bouncy castle)
Note: you will have to add the bouncycastle provider to your VM too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question but it sounds like you want the actual contents of the key - the real value of the key, as a sequence of bytes, which will do the encryption.

The text org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEPBEKEY@12345678 is not the real value of the key. That just means that the JCEPBEKEY class did not override the default toString implementation. To get the real value of the key as a byte array, use

```
byte [] keyBytes = key.getEncoded();
```

[update/retraction]

On the JVM I would use the following to print this as a hex string:

```
String keyString = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(keyBytes);
```

But as noted, this is not available on Android. The answer from @user1024882 looks like a fine approach that would work on either platform.

Comment: Keep in mind that `java.xml.bind`, etc. is not available on Android, but there are other ways to convert to hex (`BigInteger`, `String.format()`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

instead using the javax.xml lib you can use

```
static String byteToHex(byte[] keyBytes) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : keyBytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("%1$02X", b));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```